# Changing Multiple Influences Simultaneously

Tags: rigging, bones

I'm a new Blender 2.8 user, and I am creating my rig for the first time. 
Is it possible to select and change the rotation constraint influence of multiple bones at the same time? My rig goes back and fourth between motion capture data, and custom tweeking data. Sometimes I want the influence to be closer to the motion capture, sometimes I want it to be more influenced by the custom tweek skeleton.

But when I try to select multiple bones and change influence, it only changes the last bone I selected. There are about 50 bones including fingers so changing them one at a time is extremely tedious. I feel like there has to be a quicker way, but I haven't been able to find it.

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a custom property and drivers to do do this.

Basically you do the following:

1. add a [custom property](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/custom_properties.html) to your armature to control all the influences (see)
2. For one of the copy rotation constraints, right click and select [add driver->manually create later](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/introduction.html#adding-removing)
3. Go to the graph editor view, put it in drivers mode and find the driver you just created and press n to show the [drivers panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html)
4. Set its variable to a type of *single property* and select your armature as the object
5. Find your custom property and right-click on it and copy data path. Paste the data path into the path field on the driver variable.
6. update the *Expr* field in the driver panel to the name of your driver variable (by default this is var)
7. for each other constraint, you can right-click on the first constraint's influence and copy the driver, then use right click to paste to the new constraint
8. You can now update the custom property and all the constraint influences will be updated at the same time.

Comment: Finally got it to work!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @GoodNight thats great, remember that you can upvote and accept answers to indicate that they helped.

Comment: Can't upvote under 15 rep, can accept. [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134270/use-self-and-the-slow-python-expression)  .. was writing answer to this when I noticed that.