# Use self and the slow python expression

Tags: python, drivers

In putting together an answer to [Changing Multiple Influences Simultaneously](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134165/changing-multiple-influences-simultaneously) I came across the *Slow python script* warning in the drivers editor

Using a set up as [outlined here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134171/15543) driving a pose bone's constraint influence with the armature objects "prop" property

Using a traditional driver variable

[image]

And again using the `use_self` property of drivers. Since the drivers are on on pose bones, and the id data of a pose bone is the armature object then `self.id_data` is that object and `self.id_data["prop"]` (or `self.id_data.get("prop", 0)`) is the value of the custom property "prop" on that object.

[image]

However this displays the *Slow Python Expression* warning

What are the implications of this warning? How is it flagged?

*Could be related: (possibly another question) how much of self is self... In trying to game the system with drivers tried to manipulate the `self.children` via a parent object driver, only to find the collection empty in the driver namespace. The method also flagged the warning*

Comment: It's important to note that just like there's simple/slow differentiation, for slow (Python) there's also safe/unsafe. For a whitelist of allowed Python names and opcodes, see [driver not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/263879/60486) - using something outside of that list - like `self` - will require enabling script auto-execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expressions containing:

- variable names: only ASCII characters.
- literals: floating point and decimal integer.
- globals: `frame`
- constants: `pi`, `True`, `False`
- operators: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `and`, `or`, `not`,
- conditional operator `A if B else C`
- standard functions: `min()`, `max()`, `radians()`, `degrees()`, `abs()`, `fabs()`, `floor()`, `ceil()`, `trunc()`, `round()`, `int()`, `sin()`, `cos()`, `tan()`, `asin()`, `acos()`, `atan()`, `atan2()`, `exp()`, `log()`, `sqrt()`, `pow()`, `fmod()`
- blender provided functions: `lerp()`, `clamp()`, `smoothstep()`

fall into *Simple expression* category and:

- are evaluated directly, which improves performance on multi-core systems
- are evaluated even when Python script execution is disabled
- don't get the "Slow Python expression" flag

Comment: Would you consider it in many cases ignorable?, eg `self.location.x` gets the warning, making same as a variable (similar to above)  doesn't. Not using self  requires editing for each object copy to change variable target.  Appears then any use of  self in drivers requires the auto-run python scripts ..and hence slow warning if python is enabled. Cheers.

Comment: @batFINGER it depends, using the variable makes Blender treat it better and results in better multi-threaded performance, even though both are the same thing. If there are couple drivers like this it doesn't matter, but when there are hundreds, it may have some noticeable impact, I never encountered it though.