# Is it possible to access an array in a custom property in a driver?

Tags: drivers, properties

In a new project I've add a custom property to the default cube:

```py
bpy.data.objects["Cube"]["positions"] = [4,3,2,1]
```

Is it possible to access this array from a driver, so that on every frame a different value is used?

If I add a driver it is possible to access a value from a fixed position:

[image]

But I'm not able to use frame to specify the index, Blender complains about the syntax:

[image]
[image]

I've also tried to use a frame handler to set a new property with the value to be used with the following Python script:

```py
import bpy

def frame_handler(scene):
    currentposition = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]["positions"][scene.frame_current % 4]
    bpy.data.objects["Cube"]["currentposition"] = currentposition
    print(currentposition)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_handler)
```

The code is executed every time the frame position is changed and the value is set to the custom property successfully. I'm also able to use this value in a driver - but when the value is changed the driver isn't :-( It looks like this is a bug: https://developer.blender.org/T66392

Is there some other way to solve this? I could work around these limitations but changing objects directly in my frame handler, but I'm would prefer to use a driver.

I've using Blender 2.80 RC3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `self`.**

Assuming the driver is on the same object as property

Have set a custom property on the object

```
>>> C.object["xxxx"] = [4, 3, 2, 1]
>>>
```

Scene current frame is known to the driver namespace as "frame", and can be used in expression without setting up a `scene.frame_current` driver variable for it.

Set use self of the driver to true, and `self` is the driven object in expression.

[image]

```
self["xxxx"][int(frame) % 4]
```

*Driver variables by default are floats, hence the need to typecast `frame`*

**Getting Fancy**

Can add pretty much anything to the driver namespace.

A simple wrapper class with a move method using the "xxxx" custom property if defined else use a default.

```
import bpy

class Mover:
    def move(self, frame):
        l = self.ob.get("xxxx", [0])
        #print("debug...", ob.name, frame)
        return l[int(frame % (len(l)))]

    def __init__(self, ob):
        self.ob = ob

bpy.app.driver_namespace["Mover"] = Mover
```

Can now add the driver to any object

```
Mover(self).move(frame)
```

or since frame is in namespace could grab its value, *with a default juuuuust in case*

```
frame = int(bpy.app.driver_namespace.get("frame", 0))
```

and the driver can become

```
Mover(self).move()
```

The possibilities are endless.

Note when using self in drivers the slow expression warning is reported, for what are the simplest of expressions.

[Use self and the slow python expression](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134270/use-self-and-the-slow-python-expression)

Comment: So `int(frame)` instead of `frame` basically solved it. Dynamically typed languages tricks me all the time…

Comment: The solution with the `Mover` class is clever. But to get it to work I needed to enable **Auto Run Python Scripts** in the setting.

Comment: Cheers, forget about that setting.  Assigning an instanced class to namespace, instead of a class and  instancing like in example, provides a  handy way to keep tabs on driven objects and there data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two variables in the driver:

- One to get current frame from the scene properties (f)
- One to get the positions array of the cube (var)

Then the driver formula can be *var[f%4]*.

Note that if the expression fails once for some reasons, you'll need to click on "update dependencies" again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this work almost perfectly :-). For some reason Blender doesn’t show the animation properly if I open your file and press the Play-button. But if I step one frame at the time or rendering the animation if works fine. However, if I change the expression to var[int(frame)%4] everything is fine :-)

Comment: @batFinger answer is better and more complete anyway ; )