# Is it possible write a python code in a text input?

Tags: python

I would like to add a simple python code here (like when I type 1+1, it shows 2. Or like encoding some text or whatever). Is it possible?
[image]

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184906/what-is-it-called-when-you-type-math-directly-into-a-property

Comment: @batFINGER Well, that answers my question. Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can't :-(

Typically, you can right-click any field and choose *"Add Driver"* or just type an expression with a hashtag in front, but here the hashtag is just being displayed and there's no driver related options in the context menu. Trying that from the script doesn't work either:

```
>>> car = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].sequence_editor.sequences_all["Text"]
>>> curve = car.driver_add("text")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct.driver_add(): property "text" not animatable
```

---

### But... :-)

Someone like [Will Chen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/79413/will-chen) would probably *hack* his way through this problem using a driver that updates this field as a side-effect, something like setting the *Size* to `#[40,setattr(bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].sequence_editor.sequences_all["Text"], "text", str(frame))][0]` -where the `#` is there only if you input the script for the first time (when the field is not purple) to tell Blender to turn it to a driver, and `40` at the very beginning is the actual size - the rest is the nasty hack to update your text to current frame.

Perhaps a more elegant solution is to run a script like so:

```
import bpy


def frame_change_post_text_update(scene):
    scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all["Text"].text = str(scene.frame_current)
    

name = frame_change_post_text_update.__name__
listeners = bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post 
for l in [l for l in listeners if l.__name__ == name]: 
    # this is here so you can change the script and run it again without having
    # multiple listeners stacking - make sure the function name is unique
    listeners.remove(l)
listeners.append(frame_change_post_text_update)
```

Comment: Can use `if handler.__name__ == "your_listener_method":`  to remove specific handler methods. What you have changed to could be replaced with  `handlers.frame_change_post.clear()`   Re-opened.

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks! I edited this in.