# Is it possible to create a driver for the driver modifier?

Tags: python, modifiers, drivers

So, I created such a driver, I applied several modifiers to it and ran into a problem, I need some parameters of my modifiers to change in sync, roughly speaking I would like to create a driver for the parameters of the driver modifiers.

[image]

I need to add a drivers for a "Maximum X" and for a "Count" parameters, but blender does not give such an opportunity.

[image]

Perhaps there are some ideas or crutches how to do this?

Comment: short answer: no you can't. Proposal: tell us your endgoal. What animation do you want to achieve? I am sure there is a way, but you should help us understand what you want to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible write a python code in a text input?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229412/is-it-possible-write-a-python-code-in-a-text-input) In principle it's the same problem - the field is not animatable, but you can use a driver hack (on an animatable field) or just a python script to update this field on each frame.