# Using morph sliders in Blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, shape-keys

I have a character made of multiple meshes ( body, eyes, tongue, teeth). How can I make them all interact with the morphs that are on the body mesh ? 
Ex:
1) I have a morph that will make my character taller but when I use it the eyes, teeth and tongue don't move and end up where the neck is. 
2) I have a morph that will make the eyes bigger but when I use id the opening for the eyes get bigger but the eyes them self remain the same size
3) I open the mouth but the 2 meshes that make the teeth don't open.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For shape keys, what you do is what you will get.

The only option is to join all the parts together before doing the morphing.

You will control the morphing using proportional editing

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what shapes you want exactly, for some simple changes (such as height), scaling bones in the armature can be a better option than shape keys.

Otherwise you can create the appropriate shapes on each mesh and link them together using drivers.

The setup for drivers can be done along the same lines as my answer to [Changing Multiple Influences Simultaneously](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134165/changing-multiple-influences-simultaneously/134171#134171)

You can even mix bone scaling etc with shapekeys and have the bones scale drive the shapekey, although this can be a little more complicated to set up.